# I can't get Codeigniter's file upload feature to work

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried going through the codeigniter documentation and example in stackoverflow to find a solution to this problem but it didnt help. Here is the codes I have for uploading an image.
I am also using upload library through autoload.

this is my function in my controller:

```
public function do_upload()
    {


    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/dorm_images';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';
    $config['remove_spaces']  = TRUE;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->do_upload("userfile");

}
```

this is my form that is submitted:

```
<?php $attributes = array('id' => 'listing_form'); echo form_open_multipart('dorm/list_dorm',$attributes);?>

 <input type="text" name='name' placeholder='Name'><br>
 <input type="text" name='description' placeholder='Description'><br>
 <input type="text" name='price' placeholder='Price ($)'><br>
 <input type="file" name="userfile" class='btn btn-success btn-mini' size="20" /><br>
 <input type="submit" value='List this Item' class='btn btn-warning' id='submit'>
</form>
```

here is the function that is triggered at form submission:

```
public function list_dorm(){
        $this->check_logged_in();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('condition','condition', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('category','condition', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('price','price', 'required|is_natural_no_zero');
        $this->form_validation->set_message('is_natural_no_zero', 'The price field must be a whole number.');


        $data=array();
        $view_data=array();

        $this->load->model('dorm_model');

        if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE ){

            $errors=validation_errors();
            $data['insert_errors']='<div class="alert alert-danger"><p>'.$errors.'</p></div>';

        }
        else{
        $user_session=$this->session->userdata('user_session');
            $user_id=$user_session['id'];

            $data['user_id']=$user_id;
        $data['name']=$this->input->post('name');
            $data['image_path']='/assets/dorm_images/x.jpg';
        $data['description']=$this->input->post('description');
        $data['price']=$this->input->post('price');
        $data['created_at']=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        $this->do_upload();

        $this->load->model('dorm_model');
        $this->dorm_model->list_dorm($data);


        $data['success']='"'.$data['name'].'" is now listed for sale.';
            }

        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

Comment: That's cool but you are yet to tell us what the error is... What happens when you try to upload the file? Does the folder `/assets/dorm_images` have the proper permission? What does your error_log file tells you? Describe it as detailed as possible so we can help you.

Comment: there is no error. upload doesnt happen. what do you suggest for giving file permission. chmod?

Comment: the folder dorm_images should have chmod 777, have you checked the error_log to make sure you get NO errors at all? Also use the error verification proposed on the codeigniter documents http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html